# Applying to a job shows outdated personal data

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

When I apply for a job, it shows outdated personal data. This information I cannot delete / update anywhere and does not correspond to anything in my developer story, account information etc.

This data you should not even have any more as I changed it months ago. Where does it come from and why is it not synchronized with anything in my profile settings? Why is it still there and how can I manage this personal information?

Update:
As Benjamin guessed it's in the job application form. Email, phone, country - they're all outdated. My biggest concern here is that it's kept outside of normal information, with no means to edit or remove it. If someone was watching my screen, they may have seen something I didn't want them to (in this case the information is several years old).

It also makes me question from a privacy perspective what happens if I want to have my data removed? Is this part of the purge or is it kept, cause it can't be displayed any more anyway, but still part of internal records?

Comment: There is not enough detail here to help you out. What information are you seeing that you shouldn't? Where are you seeing it?

Comment: If you mean the job application form - it's pre-populated with data from the last time you applied for a job on Stack Overflow. You can always overwrite it with updated information.